# How can I save an email attachment in shared mailbox to SharePoint using MS Flow

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I need to save the email attachment (excel) to SharePoint list or library when I receive new email in shared mail box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a flow template called "Save my email attachments to a SharePoint document library". You could use that to achieve this:

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/f7a46809e53c42108034e56acf83bb79/save-my-email-attachments-to-a-sharepoint-document-library/

Comment: Is it possible in case of shared mailbox

Comment: Yes, it's possible. In the flow ,three 's a trigger called "When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox". You could use that trigger.